# How to slice data from a middle index until the end without using `length` in R (like you can in python)?

Tags: r

In python, I can slice the last four items from a five-item list (pull values from it) like so: `mylist[1:]` (note, 0-based indexing). In R, it seems that not having something after the colon is an error. In both languages, I can put the last argument as the length of the list, but that's not always convenient (e.g. inline slicing: `colnames(iris)[2:length(colnames(iris))]`).

Is there any such syntax in R?

Comment: I do miss the slicing syntax from Python, but there are a couple shortcuts that at least cut down on the typing required like `nrow` and `ncol`, e.g. `colnames(iris)[2:ncol(iris)]`

Answer (score 61):

Well this is confusing coming from a python background, but `mylist[-1]` seems to do the trick. The negative in this case can be read as "except," i.e. take everything except column 1. So `colnames(iris)[-1]` works to grab all but the first item.

Oh, and to exclude more items, treat it as a range that is excluded, so `colnames(iris)[-2:-4]` would keep only the first and all items after (and including) the fifth one.

For others coming from python, check out this [nice slideshow comparing R to python](http://files.meetup.com/1406240/Learning%20R%20Via%20Python%20%28or%20the%20other%20way%20around%29.pdf).

Comment: and you can also use `colnames(iris)[-(1:5)]` for example.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik :-) I wish I could find an "Introduction to R for Python Programmers"!

Comment: You could also use `head(colnames(iris), -1)`. The `head` and `tail` functions can be used to truncate vectors and allow negative arguments.

Comment: I think it would help this answer to explicitly state that mylist[-(1:5)] yields the sixth element and beyond (1-based), exactly like mylist[5:] would in Python (0-based).

Answer (score 40):

In R `tail(mylist, -2)`, has the same effect as `mylist[2:]` in Python.

Comment: Being picky, as lists in R are 1-index, the equivalent would be `tail(mylist, -2 + 1)`